# Can I use a (static) IP address for the domain identifier of my XMPP server?

Tags: dns, ip, xmpp, ejabberd

I am attempting to setup [ejabberd](https://www.ejabberd.im/). I will need a domain identifier (for the Jabbar ID) which is [described as](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0029.html#sect-idp622576):

> A domain identifier is a standard DNS hostname as specified in RFC952 [[3](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0029.html#nt-idp623216)] and RFC1123. [[4](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0029.html#nt-idp623952)]

Now is my question whether or not I can use an IP or if I actually need to get a domain.

Comment: Yes, u can use an IP.